# Where does Alfresco Share store it's data list entries

Tags: alfresco

Where exactly does Alfresco Share store it's data list entries? Somewhere in the file system or in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a database table called `alf_content_url` containing an url to the repository:

```
store://2012/9/24/22/58/e9d360e5-9292-4e8c-9cd4-8fe2e6724a45.bin
```

and the file itself exists in the file system containing all entries of one data list in one binary file:

```
alfresco-4.0.e/alf_data/contentstore/2012/9/24/22/58/e9d360e5-9292-4e8c-9cd4-8fe2e6724a45.bin
```

Comment: Those files store the content of nodes' properties of type 'content', such as the content of a document. Data list items will generally not contain any content properties, and so the content store is not used.

Answer (score 3):

Datalists are modeled as their own Alfresco content types (defined in datalistModel.xml) and stored in the database. Only files are stored in the file system (contentStore) in Alfresco.

Comment: Thx. a file content search in the `contentStore` directory gave the answer.